# How to change content of module when language is changed in DNN 6?

Tags: localization, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-6

I have installed a language pack for "French". When i switch language it only change text of menu items and page title , but i want to change the whole content of page in new language .

When i modify content of module , it is contain only one textbox for description , not language specific textbox . Because content in English is different from content in French .

There is any module/ editor for it .

Please suggest me any usable link or sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the Content Localization features in DotNetNuke 5/6.

Basically once you enable Content Localization, and have multiple languages, DotNetNuke will duplicate the pages on your website, along with the modules. Then you can switch between languages (assuming your skin uses the Language token).

When you browse the website using different languages (clicked via the language skin object) you will be able to visit each page and configure the content for the appropriate language.

This is an older video, but it may prove helpful

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2624/Video-DotNetNuke-Content-Localization-Preview.aspx